# Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to run a react native mobile app on my android emulator. I have react-native 0.72.6, java 8 and Windows. The error says like this:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:     
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed
 a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
```

I've been reading several answers but none of them worked for me. I see the problem could be on the gradle config but not sure of this. Anyway, I leave you here my config files and if you need any other information tell me and I add more info.

setting.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'Proximity'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
// includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1')
    }
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, for me it was the Java version. I was using `8`, once I switched to `11`, the build successfully passed.

The clue was on this error message: `Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8`

I'm using `"react-native": "0.72.7"` but on mac

Try to switch to `Java 11`, and see if it works.